# Is daemon-export-ok the most archaic feature of git?

Tags: git

This is more of a rant and may not deserve a wise answer.

The question is, is the following the most archaic feature of git:

```
touch proj.git/daemon-export-ok
```

Why couldn't it have been something like:

```
git enable-export .
```

Or something to that effect?

Comment: Git already has 157 commands. Why do you want to add another one for a very obscure bit of functionality?

Comment: Hi Kev. For consistency across different OS, would be one good reason. For getting auto-complete on the sub-command (given it is not easy to remember) and thirdly (although not important) is to invoke help on the sub-command.

Comment: It's hard to tell who's down voted this question. Clearly they didn't see the #rant tag

Comment: So we're supposed to allow self-proclaimed bad questions, as long as they're rants?

Comment: Jef, i see your point. Having said that, i think it is more a trivial question than it is a rant. Thanks to the extra two people who have *favourited* this question

Answer (score 1):

I would give that honor to something like `git cvsserver`.

If you want a command for that, you can do it pretty easily with a global alias.  It's pretty rarely used, though.  I run a couple of git daemons and use that option on one of them.

Comment: Ahh your interpretation of archaic is a bit different to mine. And in that sense, yes it does seem archaic to be using git with cvs.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggested alternative creates an entire new git command for only one purpose. That's not very useful - you still have to remember the name for this single task, and you'll have just as much trouble with that as remembering the name of the file to create.

A more likely suggestion would be:

```
git daemon --export
```

or maybe

```
git config daemon.export true
```

but still, I don't exactly see the problem with the status quo. The latter option does seem pretty reasonable... except I believe that smart HTTP checks for that file, and so it's much much simpler for it to be a single file, so it doesn't have to fetch the whole config and parse it. (I'm not a git developer - maybe there are other reasons too.)

Edit: How about an analogy? How do you get git to ignore files? By running `git ignore <path>`? Nope, by editing a file whose name you have to know. You use it all the time, so you remember it well enough. And honestly, if you're in the business of running git-daemon, you're going to remember that filename too, and if you don't, you know *exactly* where to look for it. Sounds like a good enough interface to me.

Comment: You don't think auto-complete will help?

Comment: i like your suggestion btw, considering git daemon already has *--export-all*

Comment: @superspace: auto-complete only goes so far - you still have to be aware that the command exists, and essentially remember the first word... or hit tab twice and read through the list. It doesn't excuse bad interfaces. And I don't totally like your reason for liking my suggestion - `--export-all` is an option for a running daemon, not really a precedent for a command that has an effect on a repository.

Comment: Bottom line is status quo is good. gotcha.

Comment: Also, so if my reasoning is wrong, what was your reasoning?

Comment: @superspace: I regarded it as the only possible place it could go, assuming that it isn't modified to use a config parameter instead. (Which, actually, might be just as good of an idea... except as you say, status quo is good: you don't want to break existing repositories/daemons, and there could be other issues - see my edits.)

Comment: I think we are having a great conversation about this. Why close it?